# Free Alternative to iTunes iPhone/iPad sync

Tags: gratis, backup, media-manager, itunes, data-transfer

I'm looking for a free alternative to iTunes's iPhone/iPad sync manager. I would like to be able to transfer the following between my computer and my device,

- Music
- Videos
- Audiobooks
- Images
- Contacts
- eBooks
- Apps
- Messages

I would also like to make backups of

- Contacts
- Call history
- Notes
- The entire system itself

I would like this software to be free and run on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question here, I use SyncIOS for a few years now and it's awesome. It meets all my requirements and does so much more. It's free to use but if wanted, you can pay for a pro version that disable ad's and adds a few more features.

> ## [SyncIOS](http://www.syncios.com/features.html)
>
> Syncios is powerful iPad/iPhone/iPod to PC transfer which offers you ultimate solution for transferring media contents between iOS devices and PC . As an iOS device manager, Syncios can access to any file in iDevice like iPod touch, iPhone or iPhone 4S, iPhone 5, iPhone 5C, iPhone 5S, iPad, the new iPad, iPad Mini, iPad 4, helping you manage and export apps, photos, music, ringtone, videos, and eBooks to any desired PC for backup.
>
> [image: SyncIOS UI]

Answer (score 1):

I use iFunbox in the "Classic" mode. It has many features and provides even SSH tunneling / shell console for the jailbroken phones. You can backup your applications including all settings into the IPA files.

http://www.i-funbox.com/